# How can I label vertices of a graph with non-empty sets using Tikz Package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

[image]I need to assign non-empty sets (instead of numbers) to the vertices of a graph. This may be called set-labeling of graphs. A graph with vertices having set-labels may be called set-labeled graphs (see the given figure). How can I draw set-labeled graphs using Tikz Package in LaTeX?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal compilable code example (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: I don't think there is anything special about numbers in the context of TikZ nodes, so if you can make a graph with numbers at the vertices, then you can make a graph with something else at the vertices.

Comment: I cannot label the vertices by sets.

Comment: Why not? What have you tried?

Comment: \vertex (u1) at (45:2) [label=right: $\{x_1,x_2\}$]{};  It shows error.

Comment: OK, but please do as TeXnician asked and edit your question to include a complete example. (`\vertex` is not a standard TikZ command for example.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you got `\vertex` from, but for a normal TikZ `node` you need to enclose the entire label in `{ .. }`, because the parser is confused by the comma in the label. So use `label={right:$\{x_1,x_2\}$}` instead of `label=right:$\{x_1,x_2\}$`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,fill] (u1) at (45:2) [label={right:$\{x_1,x_2\}$}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```